# When is $\frac{2^n+1}{n^2}$ an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

Can anyone see how to solve this number puzzle?

Find all integers $n>1$ such that

$$\frac{2^n+1}{n^2}$$ is an integer.

Comment: as always, where did you get this?

Comment: @WillJagy An old math puzzle book I am afraid which doesn't have answers.

Comment: I would say $n=3$... only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Since this problem comes from number theory, then I suggest you to look at equivalent  congruence problem

$$ 2^n+1=k n^2 \implies 2^n \equiv -1\pmod{n^2} .$$

Check [this, page 33](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/SatoNT.pdf).

Comment: Oh, thanks.  The solution there isn't that simple!

Comment: @motl737: You are lucky. The whole idea was to shift the equivalent congruence form then look for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked here: [How many rationals of the form $\large \frac{2^n+1}{n^2}$ are integers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97229/how-many-rationals-of-the-form-large-frac2n1n2-are-integers)

Where a link to the answer was given: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asdas/imo/imo/isoln/isoln903.html