# For which positive integers $n$ is $2^n+1$ divisible by $n^2$

Tags: arithmetic

I would like to show that if $n\in\mathbf{N}^{\star} = \mathbf{N}\backslash\{0\}$ is such that $n^2$ divides $2^n + 1$ then $n=1$ or $n=3$. If $n$ is a prime number $p$ it by obvious (and then $p=3$) by writing $2^p = (1+1)^p$ and using the fact that the binomial coefficient ${p}\choose{i}$ is divisible by $p$ when $0<i<p$. I cannot see what happens for a non prime $n$. Knowing that $n$ also divides $2^n + 1$ shows that $n$ belongs to a well-known sequence :

https://oeis.org/A006521

but this doesn't seem to help so far.

**Remark.** For those for which the question about noting $\mathbf{N}$ or $\mathbb{N}$ is easier than the "real" question, see : https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6726/mathbb-versus-mathbf

Comment: The comment + my answer to it are enough, no need to edit, and no need to replace \mathbf by \mathbb, we're not on a blackboard.

Comment: the set of natural numbers is given by `\mathbb N` = $\mathbb N$.  Of course, if you want to play games, you can call the set $\bf H^{\diamond}$, so long as you define it clearly.

Comment: It's given (i.e. written) like this on a blackboard, in books normally it's (and it should be) $\mathbf{N}$, the double bar being for mimicking bold on a blackboard.

Comment: No, it is usually $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: No, it's not just "no", see https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6726/mathbb-versus-mathbf

Comment: I like the fact of downvoting a question simply for a matter of notation, especially when the notation is not unique. You could do the same for me saying "positive" when in english it means "strictly positive", etc etc ... Please, focus on the maths. Thx !

Comment: Yes, you should focus on the maths. Your last comments are not about math.

Comment: The thing is, 11house, this isn't HSM.  This is Mathematics.SE

Comment: You start it by forcing me to defend my notation? Therefore you can reproach me to do it. Would it be no remark about my notation, I wouldn't start a debate on it.

Comment: Where is it written in M.SE that this notation prevails ?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes - from the presentation, I get the impression the OP has invested time in the problem, giving a high-level overview of what they're thinking and included a relevant OEIS link.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Cmathbf vs https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Cmathbb is a 1 vs 10 proportion the first being roughly 35k, which is not that small.

Comment: +1 to pjs36's comment.  In fact, $\bf N$ comes *before* $\Bbb N$ in [Wiki's article on $\bf N$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Notation).

Comment: @pjs36 I wouldn't call this high level. The problem might be more difficult than just binomial coefficients. I think we should return to math, and stop the discussion about notation.

Comment: It's the authority fallacy : as you have 0 reputation, you are wrong against some having >>0 reputation.

Comment: @DietrichBurde +1.

Comment: I think we have established a "policy" not to overrule the author's choice of font. Not when it is a choice between bold and blackboard bold. Not when it is a question of whether the $d$ in a differential $dx$ should be upright or not. Not ... Just **LET IT BE!!**

Comment: $n^2|2^n+1$ does not hold for $4\le n\le 10^6$ (calculated with PARI/GP)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many rationals of the form $\large \frac{2^n+1}{n^2}$ are integers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97229/how-many-rationals-of-the-form-large-frac2n1n2-are-integers) and [Find all $n>1$ such that $\dfrac{2^n+1}{n^2}$ is an integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203976/find-all-n1-such-that-dfrac2n1n2-is-an-integer)

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362721/when-is-frac2n1n2-an-integer?noredirect=1&lq=1).