# Prove that, there are infinitly many integers $n$; such that $n\mid 2^n+1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that, there are infinitly many integers $n$; such that $n\mid 2^n+1$.
I have found that $n=1,3$ works as well.
But I can't found any more.

Comment: A related question can be found here: (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97229/how-many-rationals-of-the-form-large-frac2n1n2-are-integers/424244#424244), which shows that only $n = 1,3$ can satisfy $n^2 | 2^n + 1$.

Comment: It also works for $9$ and $27$ among others.  Do you notice something convenient about the pattern $1,3,9,27$?  Can you make a conjecture using this pattern so far?  Can you prove your conjecture is true?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A006521

Closed under multiplication: if x and y are terms then so is x*y.

Comment: I am posting this comment again here in case the other thread that asks this question is deleted.  See IMO 2000, Problem 5.  You can demand that $n$ has exactly $k$ prime factors for any nonnegative integer $k$.  You can prove this by induction (on $k$).  Here is one source: https://sms.math.nus.edu.sg/Simo/IMO_Problems/00.pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lemma** : 
Let $l$ and $k$ be odd natural numbers, 
such that 
$l \mid k$. 
Then we have:

$$   a^l+1   \mid   a^k+1   .   $$

---

Let $\color{Green}{n_1=1}$; 
and let $\color{Green}{n_{j+1}=2^{n_j}+1}$; 
the first terms are as follows:

$$ 
n_1=1, 
\ \ \ \ 
n_2=3, 
\ \ \ \ 
n_3=9, 
\ \ \ \ 
n_4=513, 
\ \ \ \ 
n_5=2^{513}+1 
\ \ ; 
\ \ \ \ 
... 
$$

---

We claim that: $\color{Blue}{n_i \mid n_{i+1}}$.
**Proof by induction**:
$n_1 \mid n_2$.
Suppose that the claim is true for $j=i$; 
we will show that, 
this implies the claim for $j=i+1$.

$$ 
n_i \mid n_{i+1} 
%\Longrightarrow 
%n_i \mid 2^{n_{i+1}}+1 
\overset 
{   \tiny{\text{by lemma}}   } 
{\Longrightarrow} 
2^{n_i}+1 \mid 2^{n_{i+1}}+1 
{\Longrightarrow} 
n_{i+1} \mid n_{i+2} 
$$

---

But notice that 
the statement 
$\color{Blue}{n_i \mid n_{i+1}}$ 
is equivalent to 
$\color{Red}{n_i \mid 2^{n_i}+1}$ 
.

Comment: It looks like very complicated, where this idea comes from?

Answer (score 7):

Hint: show that if $n$ is odd and $n \mid 2^n + 1$ then $3n \mid 2^{3n} + 1$.

Comment: Thanks; but how did you guess this?

Comment: @shabnamjamali I noticed $9 \mid 2^9 + 1$ and thought maybe there was a reason for it. Also $k=3$ is the least number such that $2^n+1$ evidently divides $2^{kn}+1$, so I was trying to check out if it helps.

Comment: n can not be a power of 2 because  2^n +1 becomes a prime.

Comment: @sirous First of all, what you're referring to are Fermat numbers, [not all of which are prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Primality_of_Fermat_numbers). Second of all, how is this related to my answer? I'm assuming that $n$ is odd.

Comment: @Adayah for 3n = 21 it doesn't work. n is odd and $3\mid 21$

Comment: @Eitank What doesn't work? The implication is true for $n=7$ since the assumption $n \mid 2^n+1$, i.e. $7 \mid 129$, is false.

Comment: @Adayah, i have solved the problem with induction. Thank you